Restoring AWS OpenSearch snapshot using python returns "status":403
I am trying to restore a snapshot from a S3 repository using a python script but my script returns error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [] and User [name=tester, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"no permissions for [] and User [name=tester, backend_roles=[], requestedTenant=null]"},"status":403}
I have a registered S3 repository, i am able to create snapshots using python script and list the snapshot but cannot restore a snapshot. I have mapped a IAM user and role using AWS OpenSearch console.
I have fine grained access control enabled and am using following article:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html
What can i do to fix the error above? Would help if i can get guidance and a article to follow to get this working.
